# Scala Removing elements within a nested list

Tags: arrays, scala

I am reading data in from a tab delimited document, there are 4 columns in each line. The first 4 lines look like:

> 1 1   5   874965758
>
> 1 2   3   876893171
>
> 1 3   4   878542960
>
> 1 4   3   876893119

The first column represents the a user-id, so ideally I'd like to remove the user-id from each row and create a HashMap where the key is the user-id and the value is an Array of Arrays. e.g. each row is an entry.

My Code looks like:

```
val filename = Source.fromFile("filepath.....")
val lines = filename.getLines 
val linesArray = lines.map(x => x.split("   "))
val next = linesArray.toList.groupBy(_(0))
```

This achieves the job - creating a Map with a user-id key, however, obviously I have not removed the user-id from each row, so I have data replication e.g. if I do `next.get("1")` it will return: `List(Array(1,1,5,874965758)...)` I would like to remove this initial entry in this array.

Additionally, when reading the lines in it creates a `String` when I call `x.split`. however, I need it to be an `Integer`. How could I  (safely) ensure this is actually an `Integer`? I have done it this way in testing, however I don't think it's the best or most efficient:

```
next.map(_.map(_.toInt))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have done the groupBy you can do the following to get rid of the first entry in the list.

```
grouped.mapValues( x => x.map( _.tail ) )
```

and you can convert the String key to an Int key by doing something like following.

```
grouped.map{ case (k,v) => (k.toInt,v) }
```

Comment: spot on thank you! I'd already changed the 3rd line to: `val linesArray = lines.map(x => x.split(" ").map(_.toInt))` so the first line of your solution slots in a treat! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Change the last two lines to

```
val linesArray = lines.map(_.split("    ").map(_.toInt)
val next = linesArray.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.tail)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. However, now when I call `linesArray.get(key)` it returns one value (row) only. I need to do something like `groupByKey`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Same comment as above after your edit. I now get: `Map(645 -> List((645,Array(1159, 4, 892054632))), 892 -> List((892,Array(1454, 3, 86610267)))`